# PWA application - display a badge on the app icon works windows but not work on android

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, badge

I am struggling with PWA and badging. I added
`if (navigator.setAppBadge) { navigator.setAppBadge(6); }`
to the push notification method(service-worker.js) and it works fine on windows(chrome browser) but it doesn't work on android(also chrome browser). Consent to notifications granted. Are you able to advise what is wrong or what I miss or maybe android requires additional permissions?

Thanks in advance.

I tried set badge without number but it also don't work. I also check if I can add additional permission for PWA app on the Android device.

Comment: perhaps, as you surmised, you need [permission](https://w3c.github.io/badging/#example-checking-for-permission)

Comment: permission is granted, I can send push notification to the mobile device

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The badge does not appear on the icon of the installed PWA app on Android. It works fine on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this aswell. What i have found is that the badging api is not supported on android.
Here is a quote from google:

> The App Badging API works on Windows, and macOS, in Chrome 81 and Edge 81 or later. Support for ChromeOS is in development and will be available in a future release. On Android, the Badging API is not supported. Instead, Android automatically shows a badge on app icon for the installed web app when there is an unread notification, just as for Android apps.

[Source (Chrome for developers)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/capabilities/web-apis/badging-api#support)

It matches what mdn's compatibility chart says where Chrome is yellow and is noted with
"Partial support. Windows and macOS only."

[Source (mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/setAppBadge#browser_compatibility)